# Zend Framework contextually load stylesheets

Tags: zend-framework

Is it possible in Zend Framework to contextually autoload a stylesheet based on a unique identifier?

I'd like to load css based on the layout and the action name by first checking if the stylesheet exists then loading it.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible and surprisingly simple to implement. I have just started trying this for myself in a small project I am working on.

[See Andy Baird's blog on this](http://devzone.zend.com/1651/managing-css-and-javascript-files-within-a-zend-framework-app/), which also includes the code you need to get you started. [He continues it in a second blog](http://leakingabstraction.com/2010/02/15/part-ii-managing-css-and-javascript-files-within-a-zend-framework-app/) which takes the concept slightly further.

He uses the same technique for both CSS and javascript files, so you may want to try it with both too.